# Connect a Python script to a database

Tags: database, connection

I need to run a script tool from ArcCatalog. It needs to access a feature class in an ArcSDE database so I can link the script to the layer as a source layer. I have connected the folder the script's toolbox is in, but the script still can't find the database. How can I connect the script to the database?

Normally I just paste the path and filename into the script tool's dialog, but that's not working. I have a script for shapefiles and a script for FC's that does the same thing. I will add a screenshot of this to the original post. The script for FC's connects to the database, but the one for shp's does not. We switched our server to a new company (MS Azure) a few months ago.

I just created the tool for shapefiles from the script for the feature classes today. I only changed one line that has nothing to do with accessing the source layer. So the other tool existed before the conversion to the new server, but this one was created after the conversion.

The script tool for the FC's has not given me this problem and this is the first time I've had to use the script for shp's.

**Tool for FC's:**
[image]

**Tool for shp's:** 
[image]

Comment: An Enterprise geodatabase connection file (`.sde`) is just another workspace to ArcPy.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question instead of commenting on your own Q.  Lots more formatting options that way, and all the information is in the Question, where folks who are pondering an answer will expect it.